# When I building my first network in Hyperledger, I failed to create channel, and give following tips:

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

1. I clone the project `fabric-samples` to my file names `HYFA`.
2. I created the file names `init.sh` and copy the content of link https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.3/scripts/bootstrap.sh to it.
3. perform `init.sh` to download binary file and docker images.
4. Then I follow the official Docs ***Building Your First Network*** to config when I execute `peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem`
5. Above command returns below error

   > Error: failed to create deliver client: orderer client failed to connect to orderer.example.com:7050: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded

How can I solve this question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the project that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same error and what I did was prune my containers and such (restart network in short). It works again. This may not be the solution for you but please add more details :)